# How to make node(s) unaffected by SKCamera

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skcameranode

Alright so in my game, I currently have a ball that can be thrown around on the screen. Also, the SKCamera moves with it (as shown below). However, I want to be sure that certain nodes are not affected by the camera, and stay in the exact position on the screen. For instance, let's say that I have a ground node in the bottom right corner of the screen. When the ball is thrown, I always want that ground to stay in the bottom right corner of the screen, and not get off the screen when the SKCamera moves.

```
let ball = SKSpriteNode()
let theCamera: SKCameraNode = SKCameraNode()
self.addChild(theCamera)
self.camera = theCamera
let action = SKAction.move(to: ball.position, duration: 0.25)
theCamera.run(action)
```

Comment: attack nodes to the camera,  that is the only way besides manually moving them

Comment: I don't know how to do that, which is why I'm asking this question. Could you give me an example @Knight0fDragon

Comment: ... camera.addNode. This is not hard.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I've done this before and it only lets me attach it to the center

Comment: I want to be able to attach the node to like x: self.frame.size.width * 0.3 y: self.frame.size.height * 0.4

Comment: By you saying this comment tells me you haven't attempted anything,  if you had set the position after adding to the camera, you would see it is not in the center.  Also, you do not want to be doing frame.size.width * 0.3 unless there is a very specific reason you want to be using the .resizeFill aspect ratio.  This is a very rare circumstance that most designers would not be picking in their game design if they are doing it correctly.

Comment: I did try it, and I figured out I need to have an anchor point for the node

Comment: negative,  anchor point just specifies the "pin" if your sprite, as if you were thumbtacking a poster to a wall.  The default value is .5,.5  which is the center of the sprite

Comment: But I don't understand why I can't just do an anchor point?

Comment: the reason of the anchor point is to determine the spot in which you rotate the sprite.  Like I said,  treat it like a thumbtack

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131539/discussion-between-josh-schlabach-and-knight0fdragon).